# How can I merge the rows returned to have a single table returned rather than multiple windows?

Tags: sql, dynamic, while-loop

This code returns a row containing an address for each of the past 8 quarter.  The rows appear in seperate windows within the results but I want to Merge the results.

I've tried adding ' Merge' as a string to the end of the dynamic SQL but this doesn't work.

UNION ALL option is what I would like to go for but when I try it I get the follow error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

--Below is the code I'm using

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_History_Building] 

        @BUILDING int

AS 

DECLARE @quarterStart int = 2
DECLARE @quarterEnd int = 1
DECLARE @yearStart int = 17
DECLARE @yearEnd int = 19
DECLARE @BUILDING_ID int
DECLARE @year int
DECLARE @quarter int

DECLARE @quarterForDbName nvarchar(4)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(max)

SET @year = @yearStart
SET @quarter = @quarterStart
SET @sqlStatement = ''

SET  @BUILDING_ID = @BUILDING


WHILE @year <= @yearEnd
BEGIN
    WHILE ((@year < @yearEnd AND @quarter <= 4) OR (@year = 
           @yearEnd AND @quarter <= @quarterEnd))
    BEGIN
    SET @quarterForDbName = 'Q' + CAST(@quarter AS nvarchar(1)) + 
            CAST(@year AS nvarchar(2))


       SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + 
       'SELECT '''  + @quarterForDbName +  ''' AS Quarter, 
       ADDRESS_POINT_ID, BUILDING_ID, ADDR_LINE_1, ADDR_LINE_2, 
       ADDR_LINE_3, ADDR_LINE_4, ADDR_LINE_5, ADDR_LINE_6, ADDR_LINE_7, 
       ADDR_LINE_8 FROM EDB_'+ @quarterForDbName +'.dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS PA 
       WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID = ' + CAST(@BUILDING_ID AS VARCHAR)

        SET @quarter = @quarter + 1  

    END
    SET @quarter = 1
    SET @year = @year + 1


END

PRINT @sqlStatement
EXEC (@sqlStatem
```

The expected result is a single result window containing the 8 quarters of address records that could be easily copied and pasted to Excel or elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, if I understand that correctly that's a very questionable design, having a database per quarter. That should be one table in one database with a column denoting the quarter (or maybe two, year and quarter). That way the whole endeavour would come down to a relatively simple and performant query instead... But that aside, you can use a table variable to collect the results of each query executed in the loops body and at the end of the procedure just `SELECT` from that. Or build a query that uses `UNION ALL` to put all the single results together.

Comment: Don't add that in comments. [Edit] the question and include it there or post a new question. And also include the code you're getting the errors with of course.